# Autodesk forge - Error while loading Model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have an IFC file that I can open with Forge viewer version 7.71 and earlier but not with versions 7.72 to 7.79. The view remains with the loading spinner.
I try with both svf and svf2 options when requesting conversion job.

Here is the error log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at O.postLoadBubbleConsolidation (f42fd425-48e8-4395-9483-8669758069f0:2:164771)
at O.postLoad (f42fd425-48e8-4395-9483-8669758069f0:2:166089)
at Function.<anonymous> (f42fd425-48e8-4395-9483-8669758069f0:2:149625)
at u (f42fd425-48e8-4395-9483-8669758069f0:2:59301)
at XMLHttpRequest.v (f42fd425-48e8-4395-9483-8669758069f0:2:62363)
```

Regards.

Comment: It's a known issue. Our engineering team is working on a fix for this. We apologize for any inconvenience had caused to you.

Answer (score 0):

Our engineering team fixed this bug and released a new viewer version, v7.80, yesterday night of my time (UTC+8). Please have a try! Again, we apologize for this problem.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#section-1

**Note.** IFC file is currently processed by the Navisworks technique. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/faq-and-tips-ifc-translation-model-derivative-api